# usestate in react for setting state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

Hi in my application we are using initialstate where the application sample data will be defined and using the context for state management, below is my sample initial state:

-

```
creditCard: {
           isSaved: false,
           lastFourDigits: "1235",
           loading: false,
           cardholder: "",
           cardnumber: "",
           cardmonth: "",
           cardyear: "",
           cardcvv: "",
         },
       etc:{}....
```

and in my component i am using usestate for setting the data as below :

```
 const { state,actionsCollection } = useContext(StateContext);
  const [cardholder, setcardholder] = useState("");
  const [cardnumber, setcardnumber] = useState("");
  const [cardmonth, setcardmonth] = useState("");
  const [cardyear, setcardyear] = useState("");
  const [cardcvv, setcardcvv] = useState("");
```

and in onchange i am setting state as below:

```
<TextField
                    name="cardmonth"
                    label="MM"
                    error={errors.cardmonth}
                    value={cardmonth}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    onBlur={validateInput}
                    helperText={errors.cardmonth && "Invalid month"}
                    className={classes.expiryDateInputs}
                  />
onchange=()=>{
  let cardMonth = /^0[1-9]|1[0-2]/.test(e.target.value);
        if (cardMonth === true) {
          setcardmonth(e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, "").slice(0, 2));
          setErrors({ ...errors, cardmonth: false });
        } else {
          setErrors({ ...errors, cardmonth: true });
        }
        if (state.creditCard.cardyear !== "") {
          validateExpiryDate();
        }
```

}

passing states to non related components using below code:

```
const validateForm = () => {
    return actionsCollection.booking.validateForm(
      errors,
      setErrors,
      cardholder,
      setcardholder,
      cardnumber,
      setcardnumber,
      cardType,
      setCardType,
      cardmonth,
      setcardmonth,
      cardyear,
      setcardyear,
      cardcvv,
      setcardcvv,
      isCurrentCaseIncluded,
      cardYearValue
    );
  };
```

and in actions i am using this code:

```
const validateForm = (
    errors,
    setErrors,
    cardholder,
    setcardholder,
    cardnumber,
    setcardnumber,
    cardType,
    setCardType,
    cardmonth,
    setcardmonth,
    cardyear,
    setcardyear,
    cardcvv,
    setcardcvv,
    isCurrentCaseIncluded,
    cardYearValue
  ) => {
some validation logic.....
}
```

is this the correct way what i am doing, can anyone please tell me what i am doing in onchange and in html code is correct or not..

Answer (score 0):

If you need to validate your input inside `onChange` this code is perfectly fine.
But ,It's not a good idea to validate input on the `onChange` event . Put your validation logic inside `onBlur` or `onSubmit` events and in `onChange` event , simply set state to event value.
also, I would recommend better naming convention.

```js
onChange={(e)=>handleOnChange(e)}

///////////

handleOnChange=(event)=>{
          setcardmonth(event.target.value);
}

// move your validation logic to onBlur or onSubmit
```

Comment: in background render is refreshing when some api is running in application so the textbox is becoming empty , if i give value as state.creditCard.cardmonth, then it is not changing

Comment: Please check my edited question

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have defined your `initialState` up on the context/global level, but at the same time redefined it in one of your local component with a bunch more individual state:

```
  const { state } = useContext(StateContext);
  const [cardholder, setcardholder] = useState("");
  const [cardnumber, setcardnumber] = useState("");
  const [cardmonth, setcardmonth] = useState("");
  const [cardyear, setcardyear] = useState("");
  const [cardcvv, setcardcvv] = useState("");
```

That effectly makes your `onChange` function only update the state you redefined in your component, and it does not affect your context state, and won't update UI if the UI is dependent on context state.:

```
onchange=()=>{
  let cardMonth = /^0[1-9]|1[0-2]/.test(e.target.value);
        if (cardMonth === true) {
          setcardmonth(e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, "").slice(0, 2));
          setErrors({ ...errors, cardmonth: false });
        } else {
          setErrors({ ...errors, cardmonth: true });
        }
        if (state.creditCard.cardyear !== "") {
          validateExpiryDate();
        }
```

Meaning you are doing some extra unnecessary work by simplying redefinning things/states.

You can do one of the three ways:

1. Go straight for local state without global state, and if some child components needs them, you can just pass props and drill them down;
2. Or combine global and local state: for those states that need to be shared between different non-related components, you define it in global level, ie. your `initialstate`, for those that doesn't, put them in a local state;
3. Or go straight for global state.

On the straight global state approach, you can combine `useReducer` with `context`, and that makes updating state more managable(considering your `initialstate` is relatively complex), otherwise, you can pass setState function:

```
const { state, setState } = useContext(StateContext); // <- pass down setState from context as well
// no need for local states

// this is how to use state value from context:
<TextField
    name="cardmonth"
    label="MM"
    error={errors.cardmonth}
    value={state.cardmonth} // <- access state value using dot notation
    onChange={onChange}
    onBlur={validateInput}
    helperText={errors.cardmonth && "Invalid month"}
    className={classes.expiryDateInputs}
/>

// this is how to update value from context:
onchange=()=>{
  let cardMonth = /^0[1-9]|1[0-2]/.test(e.target.value);
        if (cardMonth === true) {
          setState(); // <- your update logic
        } else {
          setState(); // <- your update logic
        }
        if (state.creditCard.cardyear !== "") {
          validateExpiryDate();
        }
```

Comment: How to give value in html then using the above logic

Comment: I need to share the states to nonrelated components using actions so i defined them seperately.

Comment: I have edited my question with ading actions please check

Comment: By "give value in html" do you mean present state value like using double curly braces `{{ state.something }}` ? It's not clear, given the code you updated, what you trying to do.

Comment: I am having fotm where it is used in different components, so I am trying to set the values to initial state and save form from actions

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer on the last code snippet, in your situation, we can use context state, and not need to redefine local state, please take a look and let me know if it clears your confusion.

Comment: Getting error as setState is not a function

Comment: Have you set up context provider and the provider value properly? Error like this `setState is not a function` is usually because of that